# jQuery Colorbox: Outside HTML (AJAX) How to close on button click of child window

Tags: jquery, colorbox

In page 1(first.aspx) I am using ColorBox to show a model popup where I am showing another HTML page inside that (outside HTML - AJAX). I want to add a button to my second page and when a user clicks on that button I want to close the ColorBox. What method should I call for that?

Comment: +1, Im trying to figure it out my self, I need to close the colorbox from a mlink and return a parameter back to parent.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
```